# Is $m(\cap_{n=1}^\infty (A_n\setminus E))=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} m(A_n\setminus E)$, where the $A_i$'s are measurable, and $E$ is non-measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We know the following property for Lebesgue measure $m$

> If $A_1\supset A_2\supset\dots$, then $m(\cap_{I=1}^\infty A_i)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}m(A_n)$

Is this also true for $m(\cap_{n=1}^\infty (A_n\setminus E))$, where $E$ is a non-measurable set contained in all the $A_i$'s (so $E\subset \cap_{n=1}^\infty A_i$)? In other words, is $m(\cap_{n=1}^\infty (A_n\setminus E))=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} m(A_n\setminus E)$?

I feel like this should be true, going by what I understand from the proof (the breaking up of the $A_i$'s into disjoint measurable sets, etc. However, I'm not sure. If the equality is false, is the following true: $m(\cap_{I=1}^\infty (A_i\setminus E)\leq \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}m(A_n\setminus E)$?

EDIT: Here $m$ is just outer measure.

Comment: Why are you trying to measure non-measurable sets?

Comment: How do you define $m (A_n \setminus E) $ which is not measurable?

Comment: @copper.hat- sorry I meant outer measure by $m$

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is true. If we let $\mathfrak{M}$ be the set of all measurable sets, this follows from the fact that
$$m(B)=\inf\{m(A) : A\in\mathfrak{M}, B\subseteq A\}$$
for any set $B$ contained in some measurable set (so that the set under $\inf$ above is nonempty). And this in turn follows easily from the definition of the outer measure (at least the one appearing [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure)).

Comment: But the $A_n\setminus E$'s do not comprise all the sets that contain the smallest measurable set $S$ in $\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^\infty (A_m\setminus E)$. Hence, $m(\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^\infty (A_m\setminus E))\geq m(S)$.

Comment: Yes, sorry for such a hurry... edited now. There's no "the smallest measurable set" generally, but there may be some measurable set containing the intersection of $A_n\setminus E$ but none of the individuals.

Comment: Yes!! This just made my day. I used this assertion (with equality) in an answer in my qualifying exam today. But the inequality will also work, and my proof will hold. Hence, I am hoping that I will pass.